# Google Calendar OAuth - CONSUMER_SECRET and DEVELOPER_KEY

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the google calendar API since 2012, but it stopped working now.

> Error response returned: Invalid Credentials

So i went through my notes and looked up how i did this. (I only did this once) I got the developer key from https://code.google.com/apis/console
They key is still there and its the same key.

But apparently i got the CONSUMER_KEY and CONSUMER_SECRET
from Google Apps for Business account (Advanced Tools > Manage OAuth domain key)

I can't get there anymore. Or i dont know how to find this in google apps. Google apps is not even called google apps anymore. Does anybody know where i have to look?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials), that error means that the access token you're using is either expired or invalid. Suggested action is to refresh the access token using the long-lived refresh token. If this fails, direct through the OAuth flow, as described in [Authorizing Your App with Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth).

`CONSUMER_KEY` and `CONSUMER_SECRET` are also known as your "API key" and "API secret".

Check these related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/606) and [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813621/oauth2-0-token-strange-behaviour-invalid-credentials-401) which might help.