# Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message

Tags: google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am using the 'Google Spread Sheet API' to fetch the data from google drive.
Sometimes it shows the following error. But as soon as i clears the session and reload page again it works well.

'Fatalerror:'

```
Uncaughtexception'Google_Service_Exception'withmessage
{
    "error":
    {
        "code":
        401, "message":
            "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "errors":
            [{
                "message":
                    "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.", "domain":
                    "global", "reason":
                    "unauthorized"
        }], "status":
        "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check the documentation about [Verify the integrity of the ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth#verify-the-integrity-of-the-id-token):

> If you use Google Sign-In with an app or site that communicates with a backend server, you might need to identify the currently signed-in user on the server. To do so securely, after a user successfully signs in, send the user's ID token to your server using HTTPS. Then, on the server, verify the integrity of the ID token and retrieve the user's ID from the sub claim of the ID token. You can use user IDs transmitted in this way to safely identity the currently signed-in user on the backend.

In a related SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17817646/5995040), they show a [document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials) that best explain how to properly handle 401: Invalid Credentials issue.

### Note:

> Rather than writing your own code to perform these verification steps, you can use a Google API client library for your platform, or calling our **`tokeninfo`** validation endpoint.

Hope this helps.