# FireStore REST API call

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am using postman to get data from my firestore api

```
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/myapp-ef511/databases/countries
```

but I am getting this,although my rules are public

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this?I am planning to use retrofit in future.

Comment: Not so sure, But this may can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813621/oauth2-0-token-strange-behaviour-invalid-credentials-401

Answer (score 20):

Go to Firebase console and follow the below steps.

1. Go to Project Settings (top left corner gear icon)
2. In General tab -> Under 'Your project' section it will show **Project ID** & **Web API Key** (will use it in url)
   [image]
3. Now go to your Firestore database and get the document name e-g users

[image]

Finally just hit the below url with your desired values of **Project ID**, **Web API Key** and **Document**

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/[Project ID]/databases/(default)/documents/[Document]?key=[Web API Key]`

**Example of real url:**

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/firestore-rest-api-test/databases/(default)/documents/players?key=AIzaSyDsCtB9PiFTtkJiDRmFEakbKvoohPRAGJU`

**NOTE: make sure you set your project rules on test mode to make it work. Otherwise use authentication first to make it work**

Comment: how  the info to persist?

Comment: What is test mode? Giving full read write access still returns 401 UNAUTHENTICATED

Comment: @aalimovs test mode is for testing purpose.
For production you should do authentication and then call the API

Comment: @SolutionSpirit how exactly do you enable test mode? I haven't had any luck using Web API Key to access the Firestore database at all, ended up using CLI with `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`

Comment: It says permission denied!

Answer (score 5):

The REST API requires either a Firebase Authentication ID token or Google Identity OAuth 2.0 token. The main difference between the two is that a Firebase Auth ID applies security rules and the Google ID does not. This guide on [working with the Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api) should help.

Answer (score 0):

*your rules maybe like this*

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
 
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
 
   match /{document=**} {
 
     allow read, write: if
 
         request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 1, 15);
 
   }
 }
 
}
```

**change to**

```
    rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

this work for me