# Youtube Data PHP API - Service Error "Invalid Credentials"

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-data-api

I want to upload a video on YouTube via php. To do this, I've followed [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps) tutorial to get the rights (authenticate) and [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video) to upload the video.
The authentication works as it should. The user is redirected to a google site, accepts that I have a right upload YouTube videos, etc. and is redirected to my site again. There, the access token is saved.
But if I want to upload a video, I get this error:

> A service error occurred: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "authError", "message": "Invalid Credentials", "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Invalid Credentials" } }

To test my application, I've tried to [retrieve my uploads](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#retrieve_my_uploads) instead of uploading a video, but the same error occurred.
I have no idea what triggers this error.

Here is my code from the site which redirects the user to google:

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = "Not on Stackoverflow (but here is a code)";
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = "Also not on Stackoverflow";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");
$client->setRedirectUri("my site(actual link)");
$client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth

$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($auth_url) . '">Allow posting on YouTube (click)</a>';
```

Here is my code from the site the user is redirected to from Google:

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = "Not on Stackoverflow (but here is a code)";
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = "Also not on Stackoverflow";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");
$client->setRedirectUri("my site (actual link)");
$client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth

$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
$access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
//Acces token is being saved
```

And here is the upload code (which doesn't work):

```
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = "--";
$OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = "--";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload");
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");
$client->setRedirectUri("https://www.socialme.online/YoutubeFT.php");
$client->setAccessType('offline');        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth

$client->setAccessToken($access_token);
$youtube = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);



try {
    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle($Titel);
    $snippet->setDescription($Beschreibung);
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    $chunkSizeBytes = 1048576;
    $client->setDefer(true);
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/'.$extension,
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($new_path));
    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($new_path, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
        $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
        $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);
    $client->setDefer(false);
} catch (Google_Service_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>A service error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
} catch (Google_Exception $e) {
    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<p>An client error occurred: <code>%s</code></p>',
    htmlspecialchars($e->getMessage()));
}

echo $htmlBody;
```

I've no idea what causes this error, especially as most code is taken from the official Google documents. The URL in `redirect_uri` is valid and the same as the one, authorised in the Google Console. The link to the video is valid, too.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/39697007/235354 might be useful

Comment: @jspcal I've tried that and it didn't work. There's no problem with the authentication. I get redirected and save a correct AccessToken. But I can't upload anything…

Comment: Why are there calls to `addScope`, `setRedirectUri`, `setAccessType` and other login-related methods in your _upload_ script? I think that should only set the access token you already got, and not all this other stuff.

Comment: @misorude I've thought so, too. I just leaved them there as it were so in the official [Google code](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php#upload_a_video). But when I comment these lines, it changes nothing in the output (the same error), so I think, it's irrelevant.